# http extended logging format in weblogic 9.1 access logs

Tags: java, http, logging, https, weblogic

I am trying to log the Authenticated user name in access logs. can i know how tolog it.

I have written my custom class for that.And added it to weblogic startup classpath. I am getting the error while starting the weblogic.
here is the error

`<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101231> <HTTP log file does not use version 1.0 of the Extended Log File format.>
<Jan 7, 2011 1:07:22 PM GMT+05:30> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101234> <Attempting to initialize ExtendedLogFormat application specific header: x-MyCustomField. However, failed due to exception.>`

does anyone know the issue. pls help

here is my class for that

`
    import weblogic.servlet.logging.CustomELFLogger;
    import weblogic.servlet.logging.FormatStringBuffer;
    import weblogic.servlet.logging.HttpAccountingInfo;

```
/* This example outputs the User-Agent field into a
 custom field called MyCustomField
*/

public class MyCustomField implements CustomELFLogger{

public void logField(HttpAccountingInfo metrics,
  FormatStringBuffer buff) {
  buff.appendQuotedValueOrDash(metrics.getRemoteUser());
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Need to generate a jar file with the user defined classes then need to load these in the weblogic startup classes. So no issues.

But still unable to find the username and password in the http headers.

Answer (score -1):

Use the 'x' in uppercase  ('X-MyCustomField' instead of 'x-MyCustomField')